# KendoUi Grid loading data need the order of events firing

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I know what events fire in a kendo datasource but I wonder if anyone has a list of the order the events fire. I'm trying to re-filter a grid after a read() and refresh() but can't seem to get the code working. it saves fine via the change event but I don't know where to actually try and insert the filter back to the grid so it will be filtered the same as it was before a save

```
                    dataSource: {                                    
                    type: "json",  
                    serverSorting: false,   
                    batch: true,
                    pageSize: 50,   
                    change: function(e) {
                        dataSource = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;                                                                                                                        
                        saveFilters = dataSource.filter();                            
                        sessionStorage.setItem('theGridFilters', JSON.stringify(saveFilters));
                        console.log("save: " + JSON.stringify(saveFilters) );
                    },                              
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "./grid_projectselections.php?delob=" + escape(lob),
                            dataType: "json",
                            cache: false,
                            complete: function () {            
                            }
                        },                            
                        update: {
                            url: "./update_projectselections.php?delob=" + escape(lob),
                            dataType: "json",
                            complete: function () {                                                                                                
                                $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();                                                                                                                        
                                $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").refresh();                       
                            }
                        },                                
                        parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                            if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                            }
                        }                        

                    },                        
                    requestEnd: function(e) {
                        if (e.type != undefined ) {
                            if ( e.type === 'read' ) {
                                hidesavingpanel();
                            }
                        }                            
                    },                        
                    schema: {
                        data: "data",
                        total: "total",
                        model: {
                            id: "RowID",
                            fields: {
                                RowID: {editable: false},
                                ProjectID: {editable: false},
                                ProjectName: {editable: true},
                                HostCount: {editable: false},
                                HR_LEVEL_5: {editable: false},
                                HR_LEVEL_6: {editable: false},
                                HR_LEVEL_7: {editable: false},
                                HR_LEVEL_8: {editable: false},
                                HR_LEVEL_9: {editable: false},                                    
                                OrgDescr: {editable: false},
                                GroupDescr: {editable: false},
                                RegionDescr: {editable: false},
                                SectionDescr: {editable: false}
                            }
                        }
                    },

                },
                saveChanges: function(e) {                                                                   
                    var g = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid');
                    var data = g.dataSource.view();
                    var isdirty = false;
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        if (item.dirty) {
                            isdirty = true;                                        
                        }
                    });                         
                    if ( isdirty === false ) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    showsavingpanel();
                },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order when using remote operations is as follows:

```
dataSource.requestStart

dataSource.requestEnd

dataBinding

dataBound

dataSource.change
```

All are listed in the [documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource). You can also use the following [demo](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/events.html). I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but I suspect you are trying to persist the Grid state like explained [here](http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/web/grid/preserve-grid-state-in-a-cookie.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for this ... I've got a custom toolbar button that does some bulk database updates on user's filtered rows. 

After the updates finish I call another read(); on the datasource to pull back the updated data. once that happens the filters that the user had previously selected go away. I've tried everything I can think of to reFilter the records so it matches what was selected before the bulk update and the read.